# Mega R3 WiFi: Initializing issue for serial communication in ESP8266 Module's Code

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have a Mega R3  Wifi board. I Know How to setup serial part in AtMEGA2560 (it's Serial3) But in ESP8266 Module which I programmed a code to setup a Web server and I want to transmit the data to ATMEGA2560, I don't know how I should define serial pins. I tested codes blow but none of them worked:

1. I used #include <SoftwareSerial.h> and i set
   `SoftwareSerial mySerial(7,2);// RXD: 7 , TXD:2`
2. I used `Serial1` and it transmitted some none sense data ( numbers but they don't mean anything)

Pins are fine, Baud rates too. I just need a syntax in ESP8266 Module which defines serial communication to ATMEGA2560.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

In ESP8266 module code side, communication is handled with "Serial" it self No "Serial1" or anything else;